# selecting option from hidden drop down menu

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```html
<table id="rusTable" class="groupTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody class="ui-sortable" style="">
    <tr class="groupTop ruBorder" style="display: table-row;">
    <tr id="ru0" class="siru">
    <tr class="ruOp off">
      <td class="first"></td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <select class="ruOpSelect">
          <option></option>
          <option value="AND">AND</option>
          <option>AND NOT</option>
          <option>OR</option>
        </select>  
      </td>
      <td class="last"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ru1" class="siru">
    <tr class="ruOp off">
      <td class="first"></td>
      <td colspan="3">
      <td class="last"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ru2" class="siru">
    <tr class="groupBtm ruBorder" style="display: table-row;">
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
</table>
```

I want to select the AND option

Selenium webdriver code

```
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ruTable']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"))).build().perform();
waitForElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='ruTable']//*[contains(@class,'ruOpSelect')])[1]"),30);
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='ruTable']//*[contains(@class,'ruOpSelect')])[1]"))).selectByVisibleText("AND");
```

It does hover action but does not select anything from drop down menu

> *ERROR - Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:* 
>   *(`//*[@id='ruTable']//*[contains(@class,'ruOpSelect')])[1]`*

Answer (score 1):

Try using this xpath, just call click on this:

```
"//select[@class='ruOpSelect']/option[text()='AND']"
```

Any drop downs I generally start with the "`select`" in my `xpath` and next level should be option.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

after the moveToElement action. Works for me. Then I suppose you need to click the element to select it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to select the particular option

```
 IdentifyBy By;
 waitForDropDownEnable(By.xpath, "xpath");
 WebElement element = findElement(BY.xpath("xpath for the element"));
 Select select = new Select(element);
 List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
 String values = "";
  for(int index=0; index<options.size(); index++) {
        if(!values.equals("")) {
            values += ", ";
        }
        values += options.get(index).getText();
 }
 select.selectByVisibleText(value);

  public void waitForDropDownEnable(final IdentifyBy idBy, final String controlDesc) {
             int timeout =30 * 1000;

        final long MAX_TIME_OUT = 300000; 
        final long DELAY = 250;
        final long DEAD_LINE = System.currentTimeMillis() + MAX_TIME_OUT;
        boolean isEnabled = false;

        try {
            while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= DEAD_LINE) {
                 getWebDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

             if(findElement(By.xpath("")).isEnabled()) {

                    isEnabled = true;
                    break;
                }

                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException wdex) {
            ;;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ;;
        }


     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

selecting option from hidden drop down menu
in such case i use jsExecutor. Always works for me:

```
String cssLocator =  "tbody.ui-sortable tr.ruOp off td select.ruOpSelect option[value="AND"]"; 
//find css locator of the needed AND element in dropdown. I use firepath (addon to firebug).
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssLocator+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Hope this works for you